# Maven stand alone jars with shared code dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I'm just ramping up on Maven so perhaps somewhat rookie questions. I've found various pieces to my puzzle but yet to find a clear doc on how to achieve the following.

I have some common java code which I want to share between two java applications. I've set this up using maven modules as follows:

```
Root Dir
    pom.xml
    shared_code
       pom.xml
       src
           ...
    app1
       pom.xml
       src
           ...
    app2
       pom.xml
       src
           ...
```

The `pom.xml` file in the dir is simple and mainly consists of

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
  <module>shared_code</module>
  <module>app1</module>
  <module>app2</module>
</modules>
```

The `pom.xml` in the `shared_code` subfolder just uses `maven-compiler-plugin` and `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to create a jar file.

The `pom.xml`s in the `app` subfolders use

```
maven-compiler-plugin
maven-jar-plugin
maven-dependency-plugin
```

and mark the `shared_code` module as a dependency.

This works okay, but I'm failing to achieve some goals. Firstly, my resources are a mess. I can't get resources from the shared_code to automagically be available to the `app`s. Secondly, this creates for me a `jar` file for each `app` which contains only the classes for the `app`. In a subfolder (in the generated `target` folder) I get all the dependency jars, including the `shared_code` one.

Could someone explain how to achieve the following please

1. Resources from `shared_code` are automagically deployed and made available to the `app`s. For bonus points, can the `apps` override the resources somehow?
2. How do I create a single jar file rather than a jar with a subfolder full of dependencies?
3. How do I create an executable rather than a jar?

For other bonus points, please feel free to tell me I'm approaching the problem in a non-canonical way and completely correct me.

Comment: What kind of resources would like to put into your shread_code ? property files?

Comment: Just configuration files right now.

Answer (score 1):

- For the shared resources I would use [Maven Remote Resources
  Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/)
- For creating a jar containing other dependencies & being
  executable you would need to create a so called [Fat Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

---

This should give you some hint on how to achieve your goals. To explain everything in the answer would explode the topic I think.

Maybe you can ask followup question regarding the two topics as a separate if you need further help besides the hints I gave.

Comment: Thanks. This is just the sort of answer I like. I just need a point in the right direction :) Will look into this and get back with comments or more questions.